# How to filter by host name in Wireshark?

Tags: hostname, wireshark, ip-address

Display filter in form `ip.src_host eq my.host.name.com` yields no matching packets, but there is traffic to and from this host.
DNS name is resolved successfully, and filters using ip addresses like `ip.src eq 123.210.123.210` work as expected.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem might be that Wireshark does not resolve IP addresses to host names and presence of host name filter does not enable this resolution automatically.

To make host name filter work enable DNS resolution in settings. To do so go to menu "View > Name Resolution" And enable necessary options "Resolve * Addresses" (or just enable all of them if not sure :).